# When transiting Moscow (SVO), citizens of which countries need a transit visa?

Tags: air-travel, visas, russia, transit

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Russia#Transit_without_a_visa) it seems that anyone can make the transit without a visa, but I'm not convinced. Where can I get some more official information on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Sheremetyevo Airport's website](http://www.svo.aero/en/transit/rules/):

> Foreign citizens waiting for their connecting flight are allowed to stay at Sheremetyevo Airport up to 24 hours without a valid Russian visa. The passenger should have a ticket of the relevant airline with confirmed seating for the relevant connecting flights.
>
> International transit passengers whose transfer requires their stay at Sheremetyevo Airport in excess of 24 hours, may obtain a Russian transit visa at the airport (upon presentation of their connecting flight tickets and valid IDs).

Unless you're flying from or to Belarus

> Passengers from/to Belarus should be aware of the need to have a Russian transit visa regardless of the duration of their stay at the airport.